# DataError exception instead of form validation error - max_length

Tags: django

`bill_to2` model field `max_length` is 20. When I try to send my form with value lenght more than 20 I get:

> value too long for type character varying(20) / Exception Type:   DataError

instead of form validation error. What is the reason?

```
class InviteCandidateForm(forms.Form):
    def __init__(self, user, *args, **kwargs):
        super(InviteCandidateForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.user = user
        if self.user.company.display_bill_to2:
            self.fields['bill_to2'] = forms.CharField()
            self.fields['bill_to2'].label = self.user.company.bill_to2_label
            self.fields['bill_to2'].required = True

        self.helper = FormHelper()
        self.helper.form_method = 'post'
        self.helper.layout = Layout(
            Fieldset(
                '',
                'name',
                'email',
                'bill_to2',
            ),
            ButtonHolder(
                Submit('save', 'Send', css_class='button')
            )
        )
        name = forms.CharField()
        email = forms.EmailField()
```

View(it's standard FormView from django.views.generic.edit):

```
def form_valid(self, form):
    user = User()
    user.email = form.cleaned_data['email']
    user.set_unusable_password()
    user.name = form.cleaned_data['name']
    user.bill_to2 = form.cleaned_data.get('bill_to2', None)
    user.save()
    return super(InviteCandidateFormView, self).form_valid(form)
```

Comment: Where is the view?

Comment: @DanielRoseman just updated the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My guess is that you just did not say that it should be validated explicitly. That's why it is going through your form successfully and reaching the model and you get the error.

Just adding the `max_length` property should help you:

```
 self.fields['bill_to2'] = forms.CharField(max_length=20)
```